# Reduce regex to more simple terms

Tags: regex, sh

I have some test brackets in a script, which works well for me, but I suspect there's an easier way to do this. For the expression below is there a way to do this with a single regex rather than using two separate checks?

Basically if the second number is 1 I want to match 0-9 for the third number, but if the second number is 2, I only want to match 0 or 1. I have a feeling there's a more simple way to accomplish this than using two separate comparisons and was just curious if someone knew a better way.

```
#! /bin/sh
[[ "${Var}" =~ 1.1.[0-9].* ]] || [[ "${Var}" =~ 1.2.[0-1].* ]] && echo true || echo false
```

Thanks to sln, the final result is.

=~ 7.(1.(10|[0-9])|2.[0-1])-.*

Comment: Btw.: `sh` is usually not `bash`.

Comment: Try `1\.(1\.[0-9]|2\.[01])`

Comment: Cyrus, correct I tagged this wrong. My apologies.

Comment: @sln Thanks, I see now. I was missing the parenthesis when I was trying to use an OR.

Comment: @ sln, thanks again. I needed to account for 10 as well, so my final expression is: =~ 1\.(1\.(10|[0-9])|2\.[0-1])-.* ]]

Answer (score 1):

The shell-agnostic (posixly portable) way to do this is

```
case $var in
  (1.1.[0-9].*|1.2.[01].*)  echo true;;
  (*)                       echo false;;
esac
```

Note how easily this is extensible, in a readable way, to more patterns. You could also improve readability with

```
case $var in
  (1.1.[0-9].*)  echo true;;
  (1.2.[01].*)   echo true;;
  (*)            echo false;;
esac
```

Comment: Jens, thanks this is an interesting take and yes, the readability of it is a nice touch.